# move outlook folder scrollbar when clicking on a folder in favorite section

Tags: vba, outlook

I have lots of folder and subfolder in Outlook. I would like to run a macro when I click to a folder residing in the favorites section and move the scrollbar of the navigation folder pane to highlight the folder. I have lot of subfolders and it will be easier that If I select the main folder in the favorites section that I could see directly sub folder on the navigation pane.
Is there any way to achieve this ?
Many thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to customize the Navigation Pane (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/navigation/customizing-the-navigation-pane)) using the Outlook Object Model, but you currently cannot set the current folder for the Favorite Folders section of the MailModule.